# Return large volumes of data in REST API

Tags: c#, rest, api, parsing, mobile

I am developing REST APIs for mobile apps; we have a web app, which doesn't filter large volumes of meta data. Apps are taking more time to parse these high volume of (2k records with 5 columns) metadata. What are the best ways to handle this scenario from both API & App perspective. API options are preferred..

App devs are asking to return database (sql lite, etc) by combining all the metadata routes and initial sync into a single route.. I am not finding much pointer around this.. is this a practice in industry?

Comment: Instead of returning the huge data in one go the API should support pagination. It should expect a page number as one of the parameters and return that  page of data.

Comment: this really unanswerable, there's just too many design decisions and options at play here

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya we considered pagination; but its the parsing time - de-seriliae & store into db - is the killer on app. any thoughts around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of using asynchronous streaming to send large data to front end and change the client to consume the stream

[Sample implementation](https://weblogs.asp.net/andresv/asynchronous-streaming-in-asp-net-webapi)